# monochromatic induced subgraph in a complete 3-partite graph

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

$H=(V_1\cup V_2 \cup V_3, E)$ is a complete $3$ partite graph such that $|V_1|=|V_2|=|V_3|=n$ . Color the edges with three colors.

My question is: Is it possible to find sets $V_1' \subset V_1, V_2' \subset V_2$ and $V_3' \subset V_3$, such that all edges between $V_1', V_2'$ and $V_3'$ have the same color and also $|V_i'|\geq \epsilon n$ for $i=1,2,3.$?

Could someone please give a reference for this problem?

Comment: By "color the triangles", you just mean color the edges, don't you?

Comment: Assign a color to a triangle means to color the three edges of the triangle with that special color.

Comment: @bof: Thank you for your suggestion. I just edited.

Comment: This fails very hard, as you can colour all of the edges from $V_1$ to $V_2$ red and all other edges blue and not even have any monochromatic triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Of course no, even for the bipartite graph and two colors. Considering the random coloring we get that the expectation of the number of such sets is exponentially small.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is the largest size that we could get?

Comment: $O(\log n)$ (the optimal constant is almost certainly unknown)

Comment: Could you please provide me a reference? I would like to see the solution. Thank you!